# Merging hash of lists in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to set /etc/hosts entries in a playbook.

I'm managing three hashes of lists: common_stubs, env_stubs, and host_stubs.

example of what I'm working with here

```
common_stubs:
  "127.0.0.1": 
    - localhost

env_stubs:
  "127.0.0.1": 
    - someservice.mydomain

host_stubs: {}
```

I want to combine these so I get

```
combined_stubs:
  "127.0.0.1":
    - localhost
    - someservice.mydomain
```

This is what I'm currently doing

```
- name: "Configure /etc/hosts"
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/hosts
    regex: "{{ '^' + item.key + '.*$' }}"
    line: "{{ item.key + ' ' + ' '.join(item.value) }}"
    state: "{% if item.value | length > 0 %}present{% else %}absent{% endif %}"
  loop: "{{ common_stubs | combine(env_stubs, host_stubs, recursive=True) | dict2items }}"
  become: true
```

but the array in `env_stubs` is overriding the array in `common_stubs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create the list of IPs first

```
- set_fact:
    list_ip: "{{ list_ip|default([]) + item }}"
  loop:
    - "{{ common_stubs.keys()|list }}"
    - "{{ env_stubs.keys()|list }}"
    - "{{ host_stubs.keys()|list }}"
- set_fact:
    list_ip: "{{ list_ip|flatten|unique }}"
```

then loop the list and [*combine*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) the dictionary

```
- set_fact:
    combined_stubs: "{{ combined_stubs|default({})|
                        combine({item: [[common_stubs[item]|default([])] +
                                        [env_stubs[item]|default([])] +
                                        [host_stubs[item]|default([])]]|
                                       flatten}) }}"
  loop: "{{ list_ip }}"
```

give

```
"combined_stubs": {
    "127.0.0.1": [
        "localhost", 
        "someservice.mydomain"
    ]
}
```

---

Next option is to create custom filter

```
$ cat filter_plugins/dict_utils.py
def dict_merge_lossless(x, y):
    d = x.copy()
    d.update(y)
    for key, value in d.items():
       if key in x and key in y:
               d[key] = [value , x[key]]
    return d

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible filters. Interface to Python dictionary methods.'''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'dict_merge_lossless' : dict_merge_lossless
        }
```

Then the tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    combined_stubs: "{{ common_stubs|
                        dict_merge_lossless(env_stubs)|
                        dict_merge_lossless(host_stubs) }}"
- debug:
    var: combined_stubs
```

give

```
  combined_stubs:
    127.0.0.1:
    - - someservice.mydomain
    - - localhost
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far... haha. Sometimes I overthink things. This problem goes away if I just template /etc/hosts and have multple lines per IP if needed.